# flash stage is in the wrong place... 0,0 is not in the top left hand corner

Tags: flash, actionscript

I inherited a flash project from someone and if I add a simple movie clip to the stage at position 0,0 it actually ends up in the middle of the screen!

What I can see is that when I open the stage in the library, in it's properties

X=350 and Y=262,05

all the subsequent movie clips which are added to the screen as by magic are added at position

X=-350 and Y=-262.05

I would really like to return to a  situation where 0,0 is top left corner. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: " when I open the stage in the library, in it's properties " , How can you open stage in Library ? Please share a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stage should not be in the library. If it is, then it's just a custom class that has the same name. Simply change the inner registration point on this object to 0,0. Another possible issue is that your child assets might have a registration point that is offset as well.

Don't be confused about the real Stage object though, it is ALWAYS* located at 0,0.

(*disclaimer: loading a AS2/AS3 swf into an Flex project can cause the swf to receive a proxy Stage... however, I doubt this is your problem)